# List sheet Tab Names on a Summary Sheet with refresh button

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to scripts and would greatly appreciate some assistance in creating what should be a simple script for my use.

I would like all sheet tab names to be shown in a list starting at cell A4 of the summary sheet.
This list should also omit 2 sheets from the list ("Summary" and "Data") and their position could be anywhere along the row of tabs.
This script also needs to have a refresh button linked to the script so that I can add newly created sheets with a click.
I know that such a script can be be linked to a trigger, but I prefer to use a refresh button

Could anyone assist with creating such a script?

Any help is gratefully received.

Comment: Take a look at [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())

Comment: I think I have not described my issue properly, and the links provided as solutions do not answer my question.  I do not want to link 2 sheets, I want to list all of the tab names in a Single Google Sheet (20+) but omit 2 Tabs called ("Summary" and "Data") from this list.  This script should ideally be linked to a refresh button.

Comment: wasn't asking you to teach me javascript.  I was looking for help in a forum that is designed to offer help.  Obviously not the right forum.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).